# Feature like FB's "X, Y and Z other people like this"

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to implement something like facebook's like widget which says something like:

```
You, Name1, Name2 and 20 other people like this
```

I fetched all my data to be able to display this HTML, but I can't seem to find the right algo to form the HTML string.

My main problem is that I don't know when to put the `and` string or the `,` (comma) string. If I just had to put names, it would work, but the problem is that the `You` string always has to be first.

I'm going to paste my code here and the output I'm getting for some special cases (it's PHP).

```
$current_user = 0;
$html = "";
$count = count($result);
$key = 0;
foreach($result as $liked){
    if($key + 1 > $limit)
        break;

    if($liked->uid == $user->uid){
        $current_user = 1;
        continue;
    }

    $html .= "<a href='".$liked->href."'>".$liked->name."</a>";

    if($key < $count - 2)
        $html .= ", ";
    elseif($key == $count - 2 && $key + 1 != $limit)
        $html .= " and ";

    $key++;
}

if($current_user){
    $userHtml = "You";

    if($count > 2)
        $userHtml .= ", ";
    elseif($count > 1)
        $userHtml .= " and ";

    $html = $userHtml.$html;
}

$html = "&hearts; by ".$html;

if($count > $limit){
    $difference = $count - $limit;
    $html .= " and ".$difference." ".format_plural($difference,"other","others");
}

return $html;
```

And in the special case where the current user is the last one to like this, it will show:

```
♥ by You, admin, edu2004eu and
```

Notice the `and` word doesn't have anything after it, because `You` should have been after it, but I put it at the beginning. Any help? I just need the logic, not the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$likedBy = array('admin', 'eduard', 'jeremy', 'someoneelse');

// check if I like it and if so move me to the front
if (in_array($currentUsername, $likedBy)) {
  $me = array_search($currentUsername, $likedBy);
  unset($likedBy[$me]);
  array_unshift($likedBy, 'You');
}

// remove anything after the limit
$extra = array_splice($likedBy, 3);

// the comma list
$html = implode(', ', $likedBy);

// any extras? if so, add them here, if not rewrite the list so
// it's "You, Eduard and admin"
if (!empty($extra)) {
  $html .= ' and '.count($extra);
} else {
  $lastguy = array_splice($likedBy, 1);
  $html = implode(', ', $likedBy).' and '.$lastguy;
}

$html .= ' like this';
```

Comment: WOW! +1 for a very nice solution and I'd give you another +1 because I've never seen so many array functions gathered in one place :) Thank you, I've already solved it in another way, but I think I'm going to switch to your solution.

Comment: PHP's array manipulation is *super* powerful. There's almost nothing a handful of array functions can't do :) Thanks for the plusses!

Comment: @jeremyharris +1 but I'm getting a small problem. If only I (or someone else (it doesn't matter because it occurs only when it's 1 person)) liked a post it appears like this; You and Array like this - Appreciate all comments!

Answer (score 1):

Eduard,
You can fix this simply by putting `$key++;` at the top of the loop and taking out all the places where you have `$key + 1` in the loop.

I think what's happening is that `$key + 1` is assuming that there is a current user.

This line would also not display the current user if they are not in the first $limit number of entries

```
if($key + 1 > $limit)
    break;
```

You can fix this by putting this after the code that looks for the current user.

In Java (I know, but its what I had running) it would look something like:

```
    List<String> users = Arrays.asList("Brian","Tom","Jack","John");
    int key = 0;
    String html = "";
    String currentUser = "Brian";
    int limit = 3;
    boolean foundCurrentUser = false;
    for (String user : users) {
        key ++;
        if (currentUser == user) {
            foundCurrentUser = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (key > limit) {
            continue;
        }
        html += user;

        if (key < users.size() - 1) {
            html += ",";
        } else if (key == users.size() - 1 && key != limit) {
            html += " and ";
        }
    }
    if (foundCurrentUser) {
        String userHTML = "You";
        if (key > 2) {
            userHTML += ", ";
        } else if (key == 1) {
            userHTML += " and ";
        }
        html = userHTML + html;
    }

    html = "Likeed by " + html;
    if (users.size() > limit ) {
        html += " and 3 other people";
    }
    System.out.println(html);
```

Comment: Thank you. +1 for what seems to me to be a valid answer, even tho I didn't try it, I just looked over it for now.